# Having trouble combining hover state and click to zoom capability (fitToBounds?)

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Extreme beginner here. I found this (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/) tutorial that does the first part of what I'm trying to do (hover effect on US States) but I would like to add the ability to click on a state and have the map zoom to the bounds of that state.

Basically looking to do something like this https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ but in mapbox gl.

Many thanks, even if only pointing out where I should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map.on('click', <layer-name> ...` to set up your click listener. This example should help you with the structure: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/

In order to properly use `fitBounds` within the listener, you'll need to "convert" the raw polygon coordinates to a `mapgoxgl.LngLatBounds` object. This example does it for a LineString (but the approach can be adapted to work with a polygon): https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/

Without knowing the names of your layers, I can recommend something that looks roughly like the following:

```
map.on('click', 'state-fills', function(e) {
    var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
    var bounds = coordinates.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
             return bounds.extend(coord);
         }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));

    map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            padding: 20
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think we're close but not quite there. Does it matter that the state-fills layer is a fill layer with a geojson source? 

After loading the map and adding the layer, this is what I've got:
    

 map.on("click", "state-fills", function(e) {
  var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
  var bounds = coordinates.reduce(function(bounds,coord) {
    return bounds.extend(coord);
  }, new mapboxg1.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));
   
  map.fitBounds(bounds, {
   padding: 20
  });
 });

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm calling the geojson data from a url:
<code>map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource("states", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/us_states.geojson"
    });
</code>
Does that matter?

Comment: Nope, shouldn't matter too much. There was a minor mistake in my original code snippet: polygon coordinates are nested one layer deeper than LineStrings. I've updated my OP to reflect the proper structure. Here's a working POC: https://jsfiddle.net/kp2csvna/

Comment: Woo-hoo! Thank you so much!